# JOIN and Group BY functions in oracle for diff columns

Tags: oracle11g, group-by, inner-join

I have Table A, B.
A=A1,A2,A3
B=B1,B2,B3

I have to do group by in table A for A1 and A2.Also join A3 and B3 display B2 for matching records.
please note i do not want to include any other column in group by function.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried...

```
SELECT A1, A2, MIN(B2) as min_B2
 FROM A, B
 WHERE A3 = B3
 GROUP BY A1, A2
```

That's the limitation of GROUP BY.  Alternative is to use analytics...

```
SELECT A1, A2, B2
     , COUNT(B2) OVER (PARTITION BY A1, A2) AS cnt_B2s_per_A1A2
  FROM A, B
 WHERE A3 = B3
```

What info are you trying to pull from the data?

Comment: i have to pull duplicate records based on the a1,a2 column and display the details for those records from a and b table